Is it possible to pass a location to the Google Custom Search API while querying it?
I'm working on integrating Google's Custom Search API into my application, and I’ve run into an issue with retrieving location-specific search results using the gl (geolocation) parameter.
What I’m Trying to Achieve:
I want to retrieve search results tailored to a specific country (e.g., Nigeria, Thailand, United States, etc.) based on the user's input. For this, I am using the gl parameter to specify the location in my API request.
My Setup:
Here’s an example of the API request I’m making:
https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1
  ?key=MyAPIKey
  &cx=MySearchEngineID
  &hl=en
  &q=writing agency
  &gl=ng
  &num=10
  &start=1

Observations:

The gl parameter appears to be correctly appended to the API request.
Despite specifying gl=ng (Nigeria), the results do not seem to reflect a location-specific ranking.
I’ve verified that without the gl parameter, the API works as expected but defaults to global search results.
The requested URL and parameters are logged correctly, and there are no errors in the response from the API.

What I’ve Tried:

Double-checked the API documentation to confirm that the gl parameter is supported for location-specific results.
Tested with different location codes (e.g., gl=us for the United States), but the results are always global.
Ensured the key, cx, and other parameters are valid and functional.
Normalized URLs and compared them against the target to ensure accuracy.

The Issue:
The search results are not ranking URLs based on the specified location, and I consistently receive "no ranking" for queries I know should work in the specified country (e.g., Nigeria). However, when I manually search on Google, the URL I’m targeting ranks on the first page for the same keyword in the same location.
My Question:
Why might the gl parameter not be affecting the search results as expected? Is there a limitation or nuance in the Google Custom Search API that could cause this behavior? Are there additional parameters I need to include for location-specific results to work properly?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Below is a snippet of me making the API request with the parameters.
try {
    while (currentPage <= maxPages) {
      console.log(`Querying page ${currentPage}, startIndex: ${startIndex}`);

      // Construct the API request URL
      const params = {
        key: process.env.GOOGLE_API_KEY,
        cx: process.env.SEARCH_ENGINE_ID,
        hl: "en", // Language
        q: keyword, // Search query
        gl: validatedCountry, // Geolocation
        num: 10, // Results per page
        start: startIndex, // Start index
      };

      const apiUrl = `https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?${qs.stringify(params)}`;
      console.log("Constructed API Request URL:", apiUrl);

const response = await axios.get(apiUrl);
      console.log("API Response Request:", response.data.queries.request[0]);
      const searchResults = response.data.items || [];



ask how to pass?, not is it possible to pass?

@jsotola please how do i pass it? cause i have tried, it refuses
